# How can I load a custom CSS for a few lines in my code?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use Bootstrap for dropdown content, and it works perfectly fine, however, it than overrides the default CSS I'm using on my website and most of the things are looking awful below that button. I have tried to unload the CSS (Bootstrap) after I don't need it with the following code, but it is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('link[href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"]').prop('disabled', true);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Link your default.css file below the bootstrap.css. default.css style definitions will override bootstrap.css

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css">
```